# zend google fusion table update

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables

As anyone any idea on how to update a table in google fusion using Zend framework?

I can get the data:

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT%20name%20FROM%201695591";
$data = $gdata->get($url);

$postcodes = $data->getRawBody();
```

But have no idea how to update a row ...
I know I have to 'call' this url, but no idea how :

UPDATE table_id
SET column_name = value {, column_name = value }*
WHERE ROWID = row_id

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this class http://barahlo.semero.com/description/Zend_Gdata_Fusion.zip

Example of usage:

```
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('your_login_here@gmail.com', 'your_pass_here', 'fusiontables');

$base = new Zend_Gdata_Fusion($client);


$sql = "SELECT ROWID FROM 596524 WHERE id = 1;";
$rowdata =  $base->query($sql)->get_array();
print_r($rowdata);

$newRowId = $base->insertRow('596524',array(
    'id' => time(),
    'name' => 'trird row',
    'added' => date('n/j/y'),
) );

$base->updateRow(
    '596524', 
    array('name' => 'new first row'), 
    $rowdata[1][0] //ROWID from insert query
);
```

Oauth login for Zend_Gdata:

```
$oauthOptions = array( 
'requestScheme' => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER, 
'version' => '1.0', 
'signatureMethod' => 'HMAC-SHA1', 
'consumerKey' => $CONSUMER_KEY, 
'consumerSecret' => $CONSUMER_SECRET 
); 

$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($oauthOptions); 
$token = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access(); 
$client = $token->getHttpClient($oauthOptions,null);

$base = new Zend_Gdata_Fusion($client);

// ...
```

Also, there is official php client library http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-php/

Comment: Thank you.The Zend_Gdata_Fusion looks good, however, I'm using oAuth to authenticate and I'm not sure how to use it with it. And for the php client library, the downloads section is empty :-(

Comment: Thanks Zyava, really useful. Managed to get it work at the end. I had an error, but it was because I was trying to update the first row, which was my headers ...