# what is the mistake in my code to work with google fusion tables?

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables

i'm having problems with accessing my database from my server.
i'm newbie in FT, so i'll describe all my actions.

1)At first i created table and made it public here it is:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S443329UwZ1

2)Then i downloaded a class to work with FT:
http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-php/source/browse/

3)After that i knew an id of a table to use: 3406706

4)Tried to run modifyed file client_login_example.php:

```
    include('../clientlogin.php');
    include('../sql.php');
    include('../file.php');

    //get token
    $token = ClientLogin::getAuthToken('dummydan71@gmail.com', '253270514qQ');
    $ftclient = new FTClientLogin($token);

    //show all tables
    echo "<h1>hello</h1>";
    echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::showTables());
    echo "<br />";

    //describe a table
    echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::describeTable(3406706));
    echo "<br />";

    //select * from table
    echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::select(3406706));
    echo "<br />";
```

But nothing is being displayed. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but the official class for FT didn't work. But another class that I found over there:

[zend google fusion table update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625945/zend-google-fusion-table-update)

worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the flush method to flush the write buffers:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php